# Binary Search Tree displaying nodes recursively

Tags: c++, search, recursion, tree

I'm getting a problem with my display functions dealing with binary search trees. The main problem I'm having is getting the count variable to increment correctly in the recursive function so that I can number the nodes in ascending order.

Would making count a global variable work?

Here is the code for the function:

(p is pointing to the root of the tree, count is initially set to 1)

```
void displayAscend(nodePtr p, int count)
   {
      if (p->left != NULL)
         displayAscend(p->left, count);

      cout << count << ". " << p->acctNum << endl;
      count++;

      if (p->right != NULL)
         displayAscend(p->right, count);
   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to show how many levels you've gone down the tree (in which case do as Scott M suggests) or are you trying to number each node individually ... if so you need to pass count by reference ...

Comment: (This looks like a homework problem.  If so, would you tag it as such?)

Comment: i'm trying to number each node individually, like 1 for the least node, 2 for the second least, and so on...

Comment: @Tyler This is almost correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the count by reference int&.

```
void displayAscend(nodePtr p, int& count)
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
displayAscend(p->left, count);
```

to

```
displayAscend(p->left, count+1);
```

and the same with the line containing `p->right`.

Comment: This will print the same number for several nodes.

Comment: apologies, i thought he wanted it to increase for each level.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
size_t displayAscend(nodePtr p, int count)
{
   size_t additional_count = 0;
   if (p->left != NULL)
      additional_count += displayAscend(p->left, count + additional_count);

   cout << count + additional_count << ". " << p->acctNum << endl;
   additional_count++;

   if (p->right != NULL)
      additional_count += displayAscend(p->right, count + additional_count);

   return additional_count;
}
```

You can use `int` in place of `size_t` if you prefer.

The reason is that each recursive call must return a count to its caller, for otherwise the caller cannot tell how many the recursive call has counted.  The outermost caller, of course, can just discard the count if uninterested.

Passing by reference is another way to do it, as another answer observes, though not my preferred way.  (I personally prefer to implement *that* strategy with explicit pointers.)

You ask whether making `count` a global variable would work.  The answer is that, yes, it would *work* for the restricted purpose of your limited exercise, but it would represent abysmal programming practice.  After all, what if you had several trees, each with its own count?

*Update:*  Thanks to @JerryCoffin for pointing out the former error in my code.  I have fixed it above.  What is more, I have tested it with the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct node {
   node *left;
   node *right;
   int acctNum;
};

typedef node *nodePtr;

size_t displayAscend(nodePtr p, int count)
{
   size_t additional_count = 0;
   if (p->left != NULL)
      additional_count += displayAscend(p->left, count + additional_count);

   cout << count + additional_count << ". " << p->acctNum << endl;
   additional_count++;

   if (p->right != NULL)
      additional_count += displayAscend(p->right, count + additional_count);

   return additional_count;
}

int main() {
   node head;
   node n1;
   node n2;
   node n11;
   node n21;
   node n22;
   head.left  = &n1;
   head.right = &n2;
   n1  .left  = &n11;
   n1  .right = 0;
   n2  .left  = &n21;
   n2  .right = &n22;
   n11 .left  = 0;
   n11 .right = 0;
   n21 .left  = 0;
   n21 .right = 0;
   n22 .left  = 0;
   n22 .right = 0;
   n11 .acctNum = 100;
   n1  .acctNum = 202;
   head.acctNum = 300;
   n21 .acctNum = 400;
   n2  .acctNum = 500;
   n22 .acctNum = 600;
   displayAscend(&head, 0);
}
```

The output is

```
0. 100
1. 202
2. 300
3. 400
4. 500
5. 600
```

So, it works.

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  Good point, my error.  Let me work on that now.

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  The tree recursion is now fixed per your advice, and properly tested, this time, too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass the count variable by reference.

```
void displayAscend(nodePtr p, int & count)
   {
      if (p->left != NULL)
         displayAscend(p->left, count);

      cout << count << ". " << p->acctNum << endl;
      count++;

      if (p->right != NULL)
         displayAscend(p->right, count);
   }
```